# Trying to change a value inside a for in loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to change a value inside a for in loop. The value Is a bool that I declared as a var and not a let but I get the error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'notat' is a 'let' constant"

So im trying to make it so that when I tap the image inside the button in my list it will change the completed (bool) value to true. And I want it so that when completed == true I get a filled checkmark

```
import SwiftUI

struct Notat : Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    var cost: Int
    var name: String
    var completed: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var modelData: [Notat] =
        [Notat(cost: 50, name: "Klippe plenen", completed: false),
         Notat(cost: 100, name: "Vaske speil", completed: true),
         Notat(cost: 150, name: "Støvsuge huset", completed: false),
         Notat(cost: 50, name: "Vaske bilen", completed: true)]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(modelData)
        {
            notat in HStack
                {
                    Text("\(notat.cost)kr").frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                    Text(notat.name)
                    Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    {
                        Image(systemName: checkmarkSymbol(completed: notat.completed)).font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))
                            .onTapGesture
                            {
                                test(notat: notat)
                            }
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

func checkmarkSymbol(completed: Bool) -> String
{
    if(completed)
    {
        return "checkmark.square.fill"
    }else
    {
        return "checkmark.square"
    }
}

func test(notat: Notat)
{
    notat.completed.toggle() //Here is the error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'notat' is a 'let' constant"
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand? *"Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'notat' is a 'let' constant"* - `toggle` mutates `completed` within `notat` which is not mutable.

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding the terms: Ask you this: Why use sometimes `let` and sometimes `var` ? What mean `mutable` and `immutable` to you? (if English isn't your first language, might need some reading/translation check).

Comment: I understood that but I was wondering how to make it mutable because I have declared it as a var not a let, btw im new to swift (Started 2 days ago)

Comment: parameters to methods are always implicitly `let`, not `var`. Also, passing structs as parameters passes copies, so eben if you could pass a `var`, you would only modify a local copy. Read up on value vs reference types.

Comment: okay but before I tried to toggle the bool in the method I tried to do that directly in my onTapGesture but that wouldn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Notat : Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var cost: Int
    var name: String
    var completed: Bool
}

//You should change the name to something more descriptive than ViewModel...
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var modelData = [
        Notat(cost: 50, name: "Klippe plenen", completed: false),
        Notat(cost: 100, name: "Vaske speil", completed: true),
        Notat(cost: 150, name: "Støvsuge huset", completed: false),
        Notat(cost: 50, name: "Vaske bilen", completed: true)
    ]
    
    func setCompleted(for notat: Notat) {
        guard let index = modelData.firstIndex(of: notat) else { return }
        modelData[index].completed.toggle()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.modelData) { notat in HStack {
            Text("\(notat.cost)kr").frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
            
            Text(notat.name)
            Button(action: {})
            {
                Image(systemName: self.checkmarkSymbol(completed: notat.completed))
                    .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))
                    .onTapGesture
                    {
                        self.viewModel.setCompleted(for: notat)
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkmarkSymbol(completed: Bool) -> String {
        if (completed) {
            return "checkmark.square.fill"
        }
        else {
            return "checkmark.square"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So basically each time you are tapping on an image, the ViewModel will toggle the `completed` property and since `modelData` is marked with `@Publish` these changes will causing the View to reload itself.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VioWHKN1eKs) it's descriped in more detail...

Comment: Can you explain the setCompleted method, I don't understand the part where it says $0.id and the for notat: Notat

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly and the video was also really helpful to understand

Comment: In ```for notat: Notat``` for is an argument label and notat is the parameter name (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID167).
For the second question, I have update the answer (see also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand